# how to pass parameters in an function object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to pass integers as min and max parameters to a function to return a random number for use in another function. I'm new to Javascript and I'm using an object literal pattern. Currently I'm getting the error "this.randomGenerator is not a function". How can I return a number from `randomGenerator` to to be used in `interaction`?

```js
bindEvents: function() {
    $('#left').on("click", this.interaction);
},
interaction: function() {
   var selector = this.randomGenerator(0, 3);
   var $columns = $('#left').find('div[col]');

   $columns.children().removeClass('show');
   $columns.eq(selector).children().addClass('show');
},
randomGenerator: function(min, max) {
    var last,      
        value,     
        count = 0, 
        getR = function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; };

    return function () {
        var random;
        if (count && value !== last) {
           --count;
            return last = value;
        }
        random = getR();
        while (random === last) {
             value = random;
             ++count;
            random = getR();
        }
        return last = random;
    };
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `this` within the `click` handler refers to the element which was clicked on, not the object that contains the `randomGenerator()` function.

To fix this problem you can keep a reference to `this` in a variable, before using `$.proxy()` (or `bind()`) to set it as the scope that the `randomGenerator()` function should run under. Try this:

```js
var obj = {
  bindEvents: function() {
    var _this = this;
    $('#left').on("click", $.proxy(_this.interaction, _this));

    // Note you can also use the native bind() method, if preferred:
    // $('#left').on("click", _this.interaction.bind(_this));
  },
  interaction: function() {
    var selector = this.randomGenerator(0, 3);
    console.log(selector()); // just for testing...
    
    var $columns = $('#left').find('div[col]');

    $columns.children().removeClass('show');
    $columns.eq(selector).children().addClass('show');
  },
  randomGenerator: function(min, max) {
    var last,
      value,
      count = 0,
      getR = function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
      };

    return function() {
      var random;
      if (count && value !== last) {
        --count;
        return last = value;
      }
      random = getR();
      while (random === last) {
        value = random;
        ++count;
        random = getR();
      }
      return last = random;
    };
  }
}

obj.bindEvents();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time reply, this makes a lot of sense. What do the   the _underscores signal?

Comment: Nothing at all. It's just a naming convention. They have no programmatical meaning